# MVVM Distribute Objects

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Maybe it is just a small step to the solution but I can't get it so far.

I did some WPF tutorials for `DataContext` and `Binding`, but I can't get how I could share the context and/or binding between (e.g.) two pages.

For example when you look at this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
<Label>Enter a Name:</Label>
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataSource}" Path="Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

<Label>The name you entered:</Label>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=Name}"/>
```

This will be the result:

[image]

It's an easy example and there is no problem running and understanding this, but what I want is:

1. Fill the `TextBox` and the `Label` from code behind. I tried to name the `TextBox` *tb* and then just call `tb.Text = "some text"` - it works. I also tried to assign a `DataContext` for both the `TextBox` and the `Label`, then create a object and *fill* the DataContext with the object - this also worked.
2. Placing the `Label` on another page.

Problem 2 is the one that is really hard for me, especially in combination with problem 1.
For example: When I create the object in page 1 constructor and assign it the `DataContext` (ofcourse) only the `TextBox` on page 1 will contain the value.

I simply don't know how to share this one object I declared in page 1 with page 2 to set it also to the `DataContext`.

Maybe I just didn't find the perfect tutorial or explanation for me to understand how `DataContext` and `Binding` really works and how I can share objects between pages and windows.

Can you guys help me out?

If you need more informations, feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Does page 2 have its own ViewModel?

Comment: @DavidBeaumont Yes, but just because I don't know how to share the same ViewModel between this two pages.

Comment: I am a beginner to MVVM too, but I believe best practice is to have its own ViewModel per a view.  I have communicated via both ViewModels using MVVM Lights toolkit, implementing a notification message.

Comment: having one VM per page is good idea, but those two viewmodels can reference the same DTO or share the same sub viewmodel. e.g: `ViewModel1.Person = ViewModel2.Person.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MySharedDataContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _name) return;
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In app.xaml create shared resource:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Application.Resources>

        <my:MySharedDataContext x:Key="MySharedDataContext" />
```

now you can use shared resource in both pages:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource MySharedDataContext}" />
```

if you want to sent Name value, better don't access TextBox directly, but set it in you MySharedDataContext class:

```
var dataContext = (MySharedDataContext)FindResource("MySharedDataContext");
dataContext.Name = "John Smith";
```

Comment: thank you for that!! It is 100% what I was searching for. I wonder why this is never explained in many tutorials. They ever assume you use just one window. The part with the shared ressources was finally the one I missed ;)

Comment: I dont know why it isn't working. Create new question and provide more details. However, I would define the array as a property of MySharedDataContext class, instead of creating array in resources.

Comment: its working... the keyword here was `ObservableCollection` ;)